# How to add block to bundle fieldset in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I am trying to add a block to the configure screen of bundled products in the create order form of admin.

I added this layout file:  My/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.composite.fieldset.bundle">
            <block class="My\Module\Block\Adminhtml\FooBar" name="product.composite.fieldset.bundle.foobar" template="My_Module::foobar.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I added this block file:  My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/FooBar.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

class FooBar extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('hello');
    }
}
```

I added this template file:  My/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/foobar.phtml

```
<?php echo "<h1>HELLO HELLO HELLO</h1>"; ?>
```

And finally I clear the cache and compile:

```
magento c:c
magento s:d:c
```

But I don't see any big-ole HELLOs in the page.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that 'Magento/Bundle/view/adminhtml/templates/product/composite/fieldset/options/bundle.phtml' doesn't call 'getChildHtml()' so my block is never rendered.  The block is there, just not rendered.

To fix this, I added my block to the 'product.composite.fieldset' block and just placed it before the bundled items like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.composite.fieldset">
            <block class="Xplorie\AttractionSide\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Composite\Fieldset\Availability" name="product.composite.fieldset.availability" template="Xplorie_AttractionSide::product/composite/fieldset/availability.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Works but I would prefer to mess around with the actual 'product.composite.fieldset.bundle' block.  But that can't be done without a little trickery (I guess: replace the template, call my own, ...etc).

Perhaps somebody else has a better idea.